# Use CommandParameter with a button outside the ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, command

I have a `ListView` binded to an `ObservableCollection<User>`, and a button `Delete`.

I want to delete the selected item from the `ListView` when I hit the `Delete` button, but I coudn't find a way to pass the selected item to the Button's `CommandParameter`.

```
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ?}" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemeberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemeberBinding="{Binding Age}" />                    
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How could you do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Binding:

```
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyListView}" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserList}" x:Name="MyListView">
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want to use `x:Name` (for whatever reasons) you can create a `SelectedItem` property in your ViewModel and bind the `ListView.SelectedItem` property to that. That way you don't need a `CommandParameter` at all because you already have that information at the ViewModel level:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyData SelectedItem {get;set;} //NotifyPropertyChanged(), etc.

    public DelegateCommand DeleteCommand {get;set;}

    void OnDelete()
    {
        //Here you delete SelectedItem, no need for CommandParameter
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserList}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
```

*Side Comment:* `x:Name` is perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't wanna use x:Name, is there any proper way !

Comment: @Schneider why not? - This is a proper way. Otherwise put a `T SelectedItem {get;set;}` property in your ViewModel, I don't understand your point, though

Comment: This could be a great idea, you mean I put the ListView selected item in my ViewModel and bind the CommandParameter to that item ?

Comment: Gratitude, that helped me :)

Comment: How can I convince my team to use x:Name, because they keep telling me it's against MVVM :(

Comment: @Schneider It's against MVVM if you put `business logic` or manual piping (`this.txtLastName.Text = account.LastName;`) kind of stuff in **code behind**. NOTHING that is **XAML-Only** (with no code behind) can ever be against MVVM.